# Accessing bin directory through nginx/fpm - php

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi, fpm

I have a been using a library called Unoconv. (Please note that in my local ubuntu [virtualbox-homestead], it's working as expected, but not in AWS.)

```
$unoconv = Unoconv::create([
    'unoconv.binaries' => '/usr/bin/unoconv',
]);
```

This is what I call in php. And I can confirm that `/usr/bin/unoconv` exists.

The initial error was:

> exception: "Unoconv\Exception\RuntimeException"
>   file : "/usr/bin/unoconv"

---

First, I though it was permission issue. So I adapted accordingly:

`My Homestead permissions: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 63243 Aug 18 2015 unoconv`

`My AWS permissions: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 63243 Aug 18 2015 unoconv`

Then I changed my AWS group to:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 63243 Aug 18 2015 /usr/bin/unoconv`

---

Then I tried editing `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` and added this line:

```
// This existed, so I didn't touch it
fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;

// I added this line
fastcgi_param PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/node/bin
```

And my nginx looks like this:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

The error has now changed to:

> exception: "Unoconv\Exception\RuntimeException"
>   file: "/var/www/my_proj/vendor/php-unoconv/php-unoconv/src/Unoconv/Unoconv.php"
>   line: 68
>   message:"Unoconv failed to transcode file"

The file path is changed.

---

Finally, I tried removing `fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;`, but nginx doesn't compile/throws a syntax error.

I am stuck on how to overcome the issue.

---

Update:

In `/etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm`, I can see `PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin`, but I am not sure how to fix this issue. Should I use `/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`? If I do, I get an error "Executable not found, proposed : /bin/unoconv"

Or is it permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

try making the binary executable by using
sudo chmod +x /path/to/unoconv

also , 'which unoconv' command will help you to find out the exact path of unoconv bin library.

also here is the link reference for your similar issue post:
https://github.com/alchemy-fr/PHP-Unoconv/issues/5

Comment: The issue was apparently was giving `/var/www/`a `www-data` group so that it can create the necessary documents. Because OpenLibrary was trying to create some temp files there. Thanks for the input